# PHP `POST` Populated Before Submit

Tags: php, html

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I was not able to find a previous question.

I have a form that accepts some user input and then upon submitting the input, a `mailto` function is supposed to happen.

My issue is that even when refreshing the cache for the browser, my `$_POST` values are already set from a previous submit. Ideally I would want the post to reset every time.

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST)){sendIt();}



        function sendIt(){
            global $disabled,$b;            
            if (!empty($_POST)){
                $name = $_POST['name'];$name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
                $branch = $_POST['branch'];
                $numb = $_POST['numb'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                if (isset($_POST['email'])){
                    $email = $_POST['email'];$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                }else{
                    $email = '';
                }
                if ($disabled!=='disabled'){
                    $b = $_POST['b'];
                }
                echo ('<script>window.location.href = "mailto:bobby@bboi.com?subject=Support Requested!&body=Contact: "+"'.$name.'"+"Bank: "+"'.$b.'"+" - "+"'.$branch.'"+"Contact Number: "+"'.$numb.'"+"Email: "+"'.$email.'"+"Summary: "+"'.$subject.'"</script>');
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
      <form method="post" action="#">
        <center><div class="user-form">
        Name :<br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" style="width: 300px" required>
        <br>
        Main Location :<br>
        <input <?php echo $disabled?> value='<?php echo $b?>' type="text" id="bank" name="bank" style="width: 300px" required>
        <br>
        Branch Needing Support :<br>
        <input type="text" id="branch" name="branch" style="width: 300px" required>
        <br>
        Contact Number :<br>
        <input type="text" id="numb" name="numb" style="width: 300px" required>
        <br>
        Email (optional) :<br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" style="width: 300px">
        <br>
        Subject :<br>
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" style="height:200px; width: 300px;" required></textarea>
        <br><br>
        </div></center>
        <center><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
      </form>
```

**EDIT** Ive played with this a lot. I realize that `isset($_POST)` will return true. I suppose I really just need a way to run my function once values are submitted. That way I can use the current `POST` values for my `mailto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

`$_POST` will always be set, it is just empty if it's not a POST request. So this if-statement will always return true.

A simple fix would be to change this to:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

But the better solution would be to check whether anything *specific* was actually posted:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
```

Comment: Ive played with all of these solutions but the issue persists.If I refresh the page (even with cache) the `mailto` is populated and opens my email client.

Comment: Then `$_POST` is not empty. If you `var_dump($_POST);` is there anything in it? Is there any code that you haven't added to your question that is manipulating `$_POST` directly?

Comment: even when clearing cache the `post` values are already set. if i create an empty array for `post` then my mailto is never populated.

Comment: if i dump `post` upon page load it has a full array with all of my previously submitted values.

Comment: That makes sense if you refresh the page after submitting the form (your browser will simply send the same request again, including the form values. Clearing the cache will not change that). What if you don't refresh the browser but just re-open the URL (in a new browser tab/window, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

When form post u can handle too basicly

```
if(count($_POST)>0)
{
    echo "form posted with fill inputs";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the  [post/redirect/get pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Any time you receive post data, you need to first accomplish whatever the data was submitted for, and then redirect to another (or the same) page. This prevents unintended resubmissions because the browser history effectively skips the submission.

Also, you should check for a specific value that you’re expecting, I.e.,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[‘submit’]) { ...
```